# Highest-level ID possible in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want the broadest CSS ID I can get. Which of the following is valid?

1) On HTML

```
<html id="website2">
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) On Body:

```
<html>
    <body id="website2>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

3) On first Div:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="website2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'broadest'? They are all valid. The higher up the DOM you set it, the more children it would apply to. That said, as you can only have one BODY, and you typically are only styling items within the BODY, adding it to the HTML tag is likely to no real advantage.

Comment: @DA. I just realized after submitting my answer that I was using ancestors and children. Haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: As usual with these types of questions, David542, it would be great if you could offer up some context in terms of what you ultimately want to do with the CSS. That can help us taylor the answer to your specific needs.

Comment: @TylerH it happens to all of us! In fact, I'm due for another cup... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html), any element, including the `<html>` element, can have the ID attribute. In [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1) the `<body>` element was the element closest to the root that could have an ID.

Answer (score 0):

As Itay said, all they works. But the broadest in this case is the first one.

Last HTML versión supports id on HTML TAG. See this [link.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Comment: While correct, we tend to frown upon linking to w3schools on StackOverflow.

Comment: The link I've share (if you read) said: `In HTML5, the id attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).

In HTML 4.01, the id attribute cannot be used with: <base>, <head>, <html>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>.`

Comment: @DA Thanks, I am just starting answering question here.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Thanks for your advice i will defently consider in future answer. I am also learning here. :D

Answer (score 0):

It should be on:

```
<html>
    <body id="website2>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

although

```
<html id="website2">
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

looks broader but I haven't use it in the past.